# Dimension of $L^p(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, lp-spaces

Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and a measurable partition $(A_i)_{i=1,\ldots, n}$ of $\Omega$ with $P(A_i)>0$.

Moreover for any measurable subset $B\subset A_i$, it holds $$P(B)=P(A_i)\quad\text{or}\quad P(B)=0$$

I was able to show that $(\mathbb{1}_{A_i})_{i=1,\ldots, n}$ is a basis of $L^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Now I would like to show, that

$$\dim L^p(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)=\sup\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\text{There is a partition }(A_i)_{i=1,\ldots, n}\text{ of }\Omega\text{, such that }P(A_i)>0\}$$

I know that $||\cdot||_p\rightarrow||\cdot||_{\infty}$ for $p\rightarrow\infty$ and I was thinking that I might have to use Young's inequality, but I do not find any good start to attack this problem. Also splitting the proof up into "$\le$" and "$\ge$", did not give me a proper idea.

I'd really appreciate some help on this one. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @GEdgar oops, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathscr{F}$ finite, then not only is each $L_p$ finite dimensional, but also they all have the same dimension, and so by a well known fact about finite dimensional spaces, al $L_p$'s are isomorphic and homeomorphic.

The dimension is the same as the number of atoms (sets $A\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $\mathbb{P}[A]>0$ and whenever $B\subset A$ and $B\in\mathscr{F}$ wither $\mathbb{P}[B]=0$ or $\mathbb{P}[B]=\mathbb{P}[A]$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please mention a reference? Because your answer appears a bit short to me. As written, I was able to show that the dimension in case of $L^\infty$ is the number of atoms. But how can I conclude that this holds also for any $L^p$ with $p\in[0,\infty]$?

Comment: The atoms of $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ also form a "basis" for $L_p$ for $0<p<\infty$ under the conditions of your problem. There is not reference, it is a simple exercise. Just think it over for a little while.